# can not access global variable instantiated from a class in another file

Tags: javascript, module

Here I have **Person** class in a separate file then exporting it to my main script:

```
export default class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and in my script i import it then instantiate an object(woman) from:

```
<script type="module">
    import Person from './Person.js'
        
    const woman = new Person('alica')
</script>
```

and this is console's error when i try to access *woman* object:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: woman is not defined

isn't woman a global object?

**Edit: I mean access through browser's console**

Comment: Everything works ok for me, can you show part of code where you get that error

Comment: @DhanaD. but i can access it through the script when write concole.log(woman). I can't access it by writing in browser's console

Comment: I think the problem described above is due to the nature of modules, you can simply not access variables from outside.

Comment: @abolghasem the variable would be module scoped. Not in the global scope.

Comment: ah my bad. I think if it's unable to interact with console is normal tho considering the security

Comment: @Palladium02 Thank you. Yes I think this is some weird aspect of javascript